# Wireguard connnection issues on Wifi

Tags: windows, macos, vpn, wireguard

I have a very strange issue regarding my connection with Wireguard. When I use it via Wifi is can connect to the VPN service on my server and I can sent packages, which will be receive by the exposes services (I checked the logs). But I get no answer for the service on the client. In one case I get a partial answer, where I receive a 302 Redirect. The client tries to follow it and then waits forever.
Additionally to that, the connection is working with a mobile hotspot (tested Android and IOS) and via a wired connection! Then I get answers from the server. This makes it even stranger..

Let me show you my setup:

Server config:

```
[Interface]
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = [PrivKey]

[Peer]
PublicKey = [PubKey]
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.3/32
```

Client config

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = [PrivKey]
ListenPort = 21841
Address = 10.10.10.3/32
DNS = 10.1.1.100

[Peer]
PublicKey = [PubKey]
AllowedIPs = 10.1.1.0/24, 10.10.10.0/24
Endpoint = [ServerIP]:51820
```

The routes that are set on the server (nothing set manually by me)

```
10.1.1.0/24 dev br-0bf5fcc52e62 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.1
10.10.10.3 dev wg0 scope link
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.64.0/20 dev br-d5796e116857 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.64.1
192.168.80.0/20 dev br-3ccf8b8eb318 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.80.1
```

When I try no to access a service on 10.1.1.11:8090 via curl (`curl -v -L 10.1.1.11:8090`) I will receive this:

```
 ❯ curl -v -L 10.1.1.11:8090

*   Trying 10.1.1.11...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.1.1.11 (10.1.1.11) port 8090 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.1.1.11:8090
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302
< X-ASEN: SEN-18244413
< X-Confluence-Request-Time: 1599383330642
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4FB43A370B32EFEE708BD04A9D999883; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
< Location: /login.action?os_destination=%2Findex.action&permissionViolation=true
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2020 09:08:50 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host 10.1.1.11 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://10.1.1.11:8090/login.action?os_destination=%2Findex.action&permissionViolation=true'
* Found bundle for host 10.1.1.11: 0x7f8768504fd0 [can pipeline]
* Could pipeline, but not asked to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host 10.1.1.11
* Connected to 10.1.1.11 (10.1.1.11) port 8090 (#0)
> GET /login.action?os_destination=%2Findex.action&permissionViolation=true HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.1.1.11:8090
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
^C
```

This last line shows that I need to Ctrl+C out of this, because curl hangs there.

Another services responds like this (or responds not):

```
 ❯ curl -v -L 10.1.1.10:8080              
                                                                             
*   Trying 10.1.1.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.1.1.10 (10.1.1.10) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.1.1.10:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
```

And here curl also waits forever..

If I use a mobile hotspot or a wired connection then everything works fine. So this should not be a NAT problem. I tested also the `PersistentKeepalive` option on both clients, but with no success.

The behaviour is also not OS specific. Because I tested it with an OSX and Windows client.

So all in all it seems that the wifi connection is the problem or causes the problem. And I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Comment: They are routed over wg0. At least when I connect via mobile hotspot or a wired connection I can access my services on the specified IPs.. That is the strange part

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Missed that this is the server routing table. Perhaps also add the client one, just for completeness sake.

Comment: Try to remove the `ListenPort = 21841` on your client config. You may have to adjust routing on server e.g. using `iptables`.

Comment: I figured it out. It was the **IPv6 to IPv4** connection. Because of this I receive incomplete/damaged packages. When I **add my IPv6 server address to the config** it works like a charm! Does anyone have an idea why?